# Concurrency Future - is get() called if its already done?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Using a `Future` like this:

```
public class Foo implements Future<Object>{
  boolean done=false;
  public boolean isDone(){
    return done;
  }
  public Object get(){
    done = true;
    return "hi";
  }
}
```

is `get()` called twice anyhow?

Comment: I don't understand. Where is `get` called in your example? Why would it be called twice?

Comment: Please show some more code.

Comment: Normally Futures represent asynchronous tasks that are returned with a implementation by an executor. The typical usage is to submit a task, get a Future, and if you do future.get() the implementation will block until the computation is done. I'm not sure in what context are you using it. more about the normal usage here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg sure, assuming the `get()` already called, will it be called twice or is the result cached by the `ExecutionService`?

Comment: The executor doesn't call `get`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But does he cache the result and respect if the work is done? OldCurmudgeon had the right answer.

Comment: Your `ExecutorService` returns a `Future` (an interface). Underneath it all though it has a reference to the implementation, which presumably has a `set` method. When the `ExecutorService` is done processing your `Callable` (or `Runnable`), it will take the returned value (or the exception thrown) and `set` it on the `Future` (and notify any waiters). That result can forever be retrieved through `Future#get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible (and in a multithreaded environment quite common) for `get` to be called many times by many threads.

If you wish to implement `Future<V>` you must implement the complete contract - including:

> [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)... The result can only be retrieved using method `get` when the computation has completed, blocking if necessary until it is ready.

You must therefore ensure that a call to `get` blocks until the task is complete and then deliver the result of the task.

Comment: Too bad, i had hope to let the `ExecutorService` sync to the instance of the class and let him cache the result by itself.